# When should I resize a Direct3D 11 backbuffer to prevent it being drawn stretched during resize?

Tags: c++, winapi, resize, direct3d, direct3d11

I've created a Direct3D 11 application that allows the window to be resized. I am drawing 2D content, and I want it to stay the same size regardless of what I do to the window, so e.g. shrinking the window from the lower-right corner should hide anything on the right or bottom, but leave anything in the upper-left stationary.

However, although I am resizing the back buffer in response to `WM_SIZE` as described in the documentation for [`IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I still see the window contents stretch or squish for a few moments while resizing before it corrects itself. This makes the window contents appear to fluctuate up and down in size while I drag the window to its new size.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that when creating the swap chain, I left my `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1`'s `Scaling` field zero-initialized, which turns out to be `DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH`. Switching to `DXGI_SCALING_NONE` fixed the problem (and reduced how often I needed to resize the back buffer).

Comment: You should also look at using ``ENTERSIZEMOVE`` / ``WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`` which avoids the "resizebuffers being called six times a second" problem. See [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_win32/Main.cpp) for example usage.